# Location in Finder of Mac OS X iPhoto albums

Tags: osx-yosemite

I am having problems locating my specific albums in iPhoto in the Finder - does any one know how to do it? I have a OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

iPhotos stores it’s images in a package named “iPhoto Library” that typically can be found in your home directory under the directory name of `Pictures/`. And if you want to peek inside that package you can right click or <kbd>control</kbd> + click on “iPhoto Library” to look inside at the contents of that file

But if you are trying to find specific albums as organized by iPhoto itself, can then look for the `Masters/` directory in the “iPhoto Library” and within there the raw/master photos are organized by year and then the name of the photoset itself. There are also `Previews/` and `Thumbnails/` directories that are organized in a similar way, but those are what they are: Previews and thumbnails. The `Masters/` directory is where the real/original photos are stored.